# Displaying data from a not connected table IF it matches a piece of information in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to limit displays of data on my regional page for those events that only occur within that region (by city). Events are not connected with the region. So in my region view I have:

```
<h3> <%=@region.name%> </h3>
 <% @region.locations.each do |location| %>
   <%= location.name %>
 <% end %>
<h3> Event </h3>
<% Event.all.order('time_start ASC').limit(5).each do |item| %>
 <p><%= link_to item.name, item_event_path(item.url_name)%></p>
 <p><%=item.city%>, <%=item.state%></p>
<%end%>
```

How do I do a comparison between Region's city (through Location table's name) and Event's city? This way I can restrict the view to only be those that match?

Ultimately I want to limit the Event section to only display those results where the city matches the location's name.

UPDATE:
Here are the models.
Location:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
 scope :ordered, -> { order(name: :desc) }
 scope :search, ->(term) { where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%") }
 belongs_to :region, optional: true
 belongs_to :spud_user, optional: true
 has_many :careers, dependent: :destroy

 validates :name, :address_1, :city, :state, :postal_code, :hours_operation, :phone, presence: true
end
```

Region:

```
class Region < ApplicationRecord
 scope :ordered, -> { order(name: :desc) }
 scope :search, ->(term) { where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%") }
 has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :careers, through: :locations
 validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Event:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord

 scope :ordered, -> { order(time_start: :desc) }
 scope :ascending, -> { order(time_start: :asc) }
 scope :search, ->(term) { where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%") }
 scope :by_month, ->(month) { where('extract(month from time_start) = ?', month) }
 scope :by_state, ->(state) { where(state: state) }
 scope :by_city, ->(city) { where(city: city) }

 validates :name, presence: true
 validates :street_address, :city, :state, :zip, :time_start, :time_end, presence: true, unless: :online?
 validate :valid_time_span?
 validate :valid_url?

 def valid_url?
  return true if web_url.blank?
  uri = URI.parse(web_url)
  errors.add(:web_url, 'invalid url') unless uri.is_a?(URI::HTTP) && !uri.host.nil?
end

def valid_time_span?
  return true if time_start <= time_end
  errors.add(:time_start, ' must be before Time End')
end
end
```

Comment: Please include the models in the question.

Comment: I through them in. If you notice the Event does not have an association with Location/Region. So I'm trying to compare Event.city with Location.city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setup [indirect associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class Region
  has_many :locations
  has_many :events, through: :locations
end  

class Location
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :events
end

class Event
  belongs_to :location
  has_one :region, through: :location
end
```

This will let you query from `event` to `region` and vice versa.